# Ruby：BigFloatの代替について

Tags: ruby

▶︎環境：macOS Sierra Version 10.12.3
　2進計算に起因する微小誤差の影響のない計算scriptが興味を引きました。
　以下のもので、数度の数値入力＋enterで取得した数値の合計を出力するそうです。

```
require "BigFloat"
s = BigFloat.new("0")
  while f = ARGF.gets do
    s = s + f
  end
puts "合計：",s.to_s
```

BigFloatのダウンロード先が消滅しているため、現在使えない旧ライブラリと考えますが、BigFloatの代わりとなるオブジェクトは存在するのでしょうか？　やりたいことは、誤差無し計算・10進計算です。

（適切な用語の使用に自信がありません。もしダウンロード等の手順が存在したときはわかりやすく説明いただけますと幸いです。）

Comment: Internet Archive で消滅以前のウェブページを見ると、`Maintenance of BigFloat has been stopped, use BigDecimal which is bundled from Ruby-1.8 instead.` となっています。

Comment: Sierraは現在手元にないのでわからないのですが、OS X 10.11.5 El Capitanに付属のRubyでは普通にBigDecimalライブラリが`require 'bigdecimal'`するだけで使えました。BigDecimalのドキュメントは例えば[こちら](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.0.0/libdoc/bigdecimal/rdoc/BigDecimal.html)にあります。探せば日本語のものもあると思いますので、試してみてはいかがでしょうか。

Answer (score 2, accepted):

標準でバンドルされる[bigdecimalライブラリ](https://docs.ruby-lang.org/ja/2.0.0/library/bigdecimal.html)のBigDecimalを使用してください。macOS Sierra標準のRubyにもバンドルされています。

```
require 'bigdecimal'
s = ARGF.each_line.inject(BigDecimal('0')) do |sum, line|
  sum + BigDecimal(line)
end
puts "合計：#{s.to_s('f')}"
```

なお、macOS Sierra標準のRubyは2.0.0p648と古いバージョンのため、最新の機能が使えず、パフォーマンスもいささか悪いです。配布してどのMacでも使用できる物を作成するといった事情がなければ、Homebrewやrbenv + ruby-build等で最新バージョンを入れることをオススメします。